# Out of memory - Google Kubernetes

Tags: node.js, out-of-memory, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an autopilot cluster which should increase the cpu/memory on demand but I am still getting the following error

I have not defined any limits/resources in the deployment. I am relying on Google to handle that automatically.

It's a node application that reads large csv files (300-400mb), parses them and inserts them to mysql db (using typeorm)
It seems it works with smaller files. The files are read one by one.
In this case there are over 1200 files (not all 300-400mb of size but quite many are)

It seems it does not work like I thought it would....
Is this a sign that there is something wrong with the js code or do I just need to increase the memory manually ?

```
<--- Last few GCs --->
[1:0x7f9fde9bf330]  4338991 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 955.5 (1037.2) -> 955.5 (1037.2) MB, 7.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.295, current mu = 0.279) allocation failure
[1:0x7f9fde9bf330]  4339001 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 956.9 (1037.7) -> 956.9 (1038.0) MB, 7.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.295, current mu = 0.279) allocation failure
[1:0x7f9fde9bf330]  4339011 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 958.1 (1038.0) -> 958.1 (1038.5) MB, 7.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.295, current mu = 0.279) allocation failure
<--- JS stacktrace --->
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have not defined any limits/resources in the deployment. I am relying on Google to handle that automatically.

I don't think that's true. Copy pasting from the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview#default_container_resource_requests):
"Autopilot relies on what you specify in your deployment configuration to provision resources. If you do not specify resource requests for any container in the Pod, Autopilot applies default values. These defaults are designed to give the containers in your Pods an average amount of resources, which are suitable for many smaller workloads."

And this: "Important: Google recommends that you explicitly set your resource requests for each container to meet your application requirements, as these default values might not be sufficient, or optimal."

So it's likely that the default resource requests and limit are too low for your application. You should set them to be a value high enough so you don't run out of memory.

Comment: Good point. I should maybe learn to read the documentation. Thanks for the pointer. It seems 2Gi is set for memory (limit and requests) if nothing is defined explicitly

Comment: I'm the same I only read just enough to get stuff working or help answer SO questions. That being said you can configure Vertical Pod Autoscaler to automatically set resource requests and limits, but it might be overkill for your case. In general knowing your application and setting the right resource request/limit is recommended.

Comment: For me I had to allocate more memory to Node with --max-old-space-size. The default size is 2gb (I think). I tried setting it to same as I have allocated in GKE but I ran into same issue that the pod was terminated so I set it to 1gb less. So far it is running fine.